# How to add multiple arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, arrows, tikz-graphdrawing

I have the following code:

```
    \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
        \usepackage{bm}
        \usepackage{nccmath}
        \usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs}
        \usepackage{color}
        \usepackage{array}
        \usepackage{setspace}
        \usepackage{fancyhdr}
        \usepackage{enumitem}
        \usepackage{tikz}
        \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,arrows}
        \newcommand\tikznode[3][]{%
          \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#2.base)]
            \node[minimum size=0pt,inner sep=0pt,#1](#2){#3};%
        }
        % \board[optional scale factor, default 1.0]{list of triples angle/number/mark}
        \newcommand\board[2][1.0]{%
          \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,0)},scale=#1]
            \draw (0,0) circle (1);
            % radial lines at angles 30°, 150° and 270°
            \foreach \a in {30, 150, 270}
              \draw (\a:0.8) -- (\a:1.2);
            % label A/B/C outside of circle at angles 90°, 210° and 330°
            \foreach \a/\l in {90/A,210/B,330/C}
              \node at (\a:1.4) {\scriptsize$\l$};
            % draw game positions
            % \a ... angle, \n ... number 1/2/3, \m ... mark  
            \foreach \a/\n/\m in {#2} {
              % node
              \node[circle,draw,minimum size=1em,inner sep = 0,fill=white] at (\a:1) {\m};
              % number inside of circle
              \node at (\a:0.6) {\scriptsize$\n$};
          }
          \end{tikzpicture}%
        }
        \newcommand\cross{$\times$}
        
        \section{Case 1}
  

\paragraph{Time 0}\mbox{}\\
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5em}@{}}
  $1=i$ in $A$\\
  $2=s$ in $B$\\
  $3=s$ in $C$
\end{tabular}
$\longrightarrow$
\tikznode{X}{$[(i,A),(s,B),(s,C)]=X$}
\board[0.9]{90/1/\cross,210/2/,330/3/}

\paragraph{Time 1}\mbox{}\\
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5em}@{}}
  $1=r$ in $B$\\
  $2=s$ in $A$\\
  $3=i$ in $B$
\end{tabular}
$\longrightarrow$
\tikznode{Y}{$[(r,B),(s,A),(i,B)]=Y$}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{90/2/,190/1/\cross,230/3/}\\
  Move
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{90/2/,190/1/R,230/3/\cross}\\
  Status
\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,>=stealth',shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2pt]
  \draw[->] (X) edge[bend left] node[right]{$P_{XY}=p/8$} (Y);
\end{tikzpicture}

\paragraph{Time 2}\mbox{}\\
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5em}@{}}
  $1=r$ in $B$\\
  $2=i$ in $A$\\
  $3=r$ in $B$
\end{tabular}
$\longrightarrow$
\tikznode{Y}{$[(r,A),(i,C),(r,C)]=Z$}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{90/1/R,310/2/,350/3/\cross}\\
  Move
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{90/1/R,310/2/\cross ,350/3/R}\\
  Status
\end{tabular}

\paragraph{Time 3}\mbox{}\\
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5em}@{}}
  $1=r$ in $B$\\
  $2=r$ in $A$\\
  $3=r$ in $B$
\end{tabular}
$\longrightarrow$
\tikznode{Y}{$[(r,C),(r,B),(r,A)]=Q$}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{90/3/R,210/2/\cross,330/1/R}\\
  Move
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{90/3/R,210/2/R,330/1/R}\\
  Status
\end{tabular}

At time 3, the epidemic stops since all personnel are recovered.

\section{Case 2}
  
\paragraph{Time 0}\mbox{}\\
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5em}@{}}
  $1=i$ in $A$\\
  $2=s$ in $B$\\
  $3=s$ in $C$
\end{tabular}
$\longrightarrow$
\tikznode{X}{$[(i,A),(s,B),(s,C)]=X$}
\board[0.9]{90/1/\cross,210/2/,330/3/}

\paragraph{Time 1}\mbox{}\\
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5em}@{}}
  $1=r$ in $B$\\
  $2=s$ in $A$\\
  $3=i$ in $B$
\end{tabular}
$\longrightarrow$
\tikznode{Y}{$[(r,B),(s,A),(i,B)]=Y$}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{90/3/,210/1/\cross,330/2/}\\
  Move
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{90/3/,210/1/R,330/2/}\\
  Status
\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,>=stealth',shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2pt]
  \draw[->] (X) edge[bend left] node[right]{$P_{XY}=1/8$} (Y);
\end{tikzpicture}

At time 1, the epidemic stops since all personnel are recovered.

\section{Case 3}

\paragraph{Time 0}\mbox{}\\
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5em}@{}}
  $1=i$ in $A$\\
  $2=s$ in $B$\\
  $3=s$ in $C$
\end{tabular}
$\longrightarrow$
\tikznode{X}{$[(i,A),(s,B),(s,C)]=X$}
\board[0.9]{90/1/\cross,210/2/,330/3/}

\paragraph{Time 1}\mbox{}\\
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5em}@{}}
  $1=r$ in $C$\\
  $2=i$ in $C$\\
  $3=s$ in $A$
\end{tabular}
$\longrightarrow$
\tikznode{Y}{$[(r,C),(i,C),(s,A)]=Y$}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{90/3/,310/1/\cross,350/2/}\\
  Move
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{90/3/,310/3/R,350/2/\cross}\\
  Status
\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,>=stealth',shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2pt]
  \draw[->] (X) edge[bend left] node[right]{$P_{XY}=p/8$} (Y);
\end{tikzpicture}

\paragraph{Time 2}\mbox{}\\
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5em}@{}}
  $1=r$ in $B$\\
  $2=r$ in $B$\\
  $3=i$ in $B$
\end{tabular}
$\longrightarrow$
\tikznode{Y}{$[(r,B),(r,B),(i,B)]=Z$}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{210/2/\cross,245/3/,175/1/R}\\
  Move
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{210/2/R,245/3/\cross,175/1/R}\\
  Status
\end{tabular}

\paragraph{Time 3}\mbox{}\\
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5em}@{}}
  $1=r$ in $A$\\
  $2=r$ in $C$\\
  $3=r$ in $C$
\end{tabular}
$\longrightarrow$
\tikznode{Y}{$[(r,A),(r,C),(r,C)]=Q$}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{90/1/R,310/3/\cross,350/2/R}\\
  Move
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{90/1/R,310/3/R,350/2/R}\\
  Status
\end{tabular}

At time 3, the epidemic stops since all personnel are recovered.  



\section{Case 4}
  
\paragraph{Time 0}\mbox{}\\
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5em}@{}}
  $1=i$ in $A$\\
  $2=s$ in $B$\\
  $3=s$ in $C$
\end{tabular}
$\longrightarrow$
\tikznode{X}{$[(i,A),(s,B),(s,C)]=X$}
\board[0.9]{90/1/\cross,210/2/,330/3/}

\paragraph{Time 1}\mbox{}\\
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5em}@{}}
  $1=r$ in $B$\\
  $2=s$ in $A$\\
  $3=s$ in $A$
\end{tabular}
$\longrightarrow$
\tikznode{Y}{$[(r,B),(s,A),(s,A)]=Y$}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{70/3/,210/1/\cross,110/2/}\\
  Move
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{70/3/,210/1/R,110/2/}\\
  Status
\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,>=stealth',shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2pt]
  \draw[->] (X) edge[bend left] node[right]{$P_{XY}=1/8$} (Y);
\end{tikzpicture}

At time 1, the epidemic stops since all personnel are recovered.


\section{Case 5}

\end{document}
```

I wish to put arrows like "X" to "Y" to "Y" to "Z" and "Z" to "Q". Any ideas? Also in cases 3 and 4 there is a issue with the arrow, it goes across the whole page, how do I fix this?
[image]

Comment: simply shift the location of the tikzmark

Comment: The name after `\tikznode` should be unique. In your document, you have lots of `\tikznnode{Y}{...}`, similarly `X` and `Z`. Rename them to `Y1`, `Y2`, ... Moreover, make sure that all points that you want to connect, are on the same page. Otherwise, what should LaTeX do if you want to connect points on different pages? Finally, the `tikzpicture` with the arrows should be probably also on the same page.

Comment: @gernot You helped me with this code a week or so ago. To be honest, I am not good with LaTex so I will appreciat your help.

Comment: @gernot And what is the best way to put he different cases so LaTex recognises where to put the arrows? I don't to leave a huge white space. Maybe you can "shrink" the larger cases(case 1 and 4) so they fit on a page and I can renumber cases 2 and 3  so they both fit on a page?

Comment: Put the parts that should stay together without page break into a figure. The purpose of `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}` is exactly to avoid page breaks, at the price that the figure cannot always stay in place, in order to avoid large gaps in the text.

Comment: @gernot I tried this but it completely ruins the document. What would do if you were in my position? couldn't you do what I mentioned above? to shrink the "larger" cases to make them fit on a page and the smaller cases put both of them into a single page? then we can attach the arrows properly on the larger cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make sure that the name after `\tikznode` is different for every such command.
- Make sure that all `\tikznodes` that appear in the same `tikzpicture` are on the same page. How should LaTeX connect points on different pages?

To avoid page breaks, put text and drawings that belong together into a `figure` environment such they can drift to a place where there is enough space. Otherwise, you have to control it yourself, like in the example below, by rearranging the text such that the space is reasonably filled and forcing page breaks by `\newpage` or `\clearpage`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
        \usepackage{bm}
        \usepackage{nccmath}
        \usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs}
        \usepackage{color}
        \usepackage{array}
        \usepackage{setspace}
        \usepackage{fancyhdr}
        \usepackage{enumitem}
        \usepackage{tikz}
        \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,arrows}
        \newcommand\tikznode[3][]{%
          \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#2.base)]
            \node[minimum size=0pt,inner sep=0pt,#1](#2){#3};%
        }
        % \board[optional scale factor, default 1.0]{list of triples angle/number/mark}
        \newcommand\board[2][1.0]{%
          \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,0)},scale=#1]
            \draw (0,0) circle (1);
            % radial lines at angles 30°, 150° and 270°
            \foreach \a in {30, 150, 270}
              \draw (\a:0.8) -- (\a:1.2);
            % label A/B/C outside of circle at angles 90°, 210° and 330°
            \foreach \a/\l in {90/A,210/B,330/C}
              \node at (\a:1.4) {\scriptsize$\l$};
            % draw game positions
            % \a ... angle, \n ... number 1/2/3, \m ... mark  
            \foreach \a/\n/\m in {#2} {
              % node
              \node[circle,draw,minimum size=1em,inner sep = 0,fill=white] at (\a:1) {\m};
              % number inside of circle
              \node at (\a:0.6) {\scriptsize$\n$};
          }
          \end{tikzpicture}%
        }
        \newcommand\cross{$\times$}

\begin{document}

\section{Case 1}
  

\paragraph{Time 0}\mbox{}\\
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5em}@{}}
  $1=i$ in $A$\\
  $2=s$ in $B$\\
  $3=s$ in $C$
\end{tabular}
$\longrightarrow$
\tikznode{X1}{$[(i,A),(s,B),(s,C)]=X$}
\board[0.9]{90/1/\cross,210/2/,330/3/}

\paragraph{Time 1}\mbox{}\\
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5em}@{}}
  $1=r$ in $B$\\
  $2=s$ in $A$\\
  $3=i$ in $B$
\end{tabular}
$\longrightarrow$
\tikznode{Y1}{$[(r,B),(s,A),(i,B)]=Y$}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{90/2/,190/1/\cross,230/3/}\\
  Move
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{90/2/,190/1/R,230/3/\cross}\\
  Status
\end{tabular}

\paragraph{Time 2}\mbox{}\\
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5em}@{}}
  $1=r$ in $B$\\
  $2=i$ in $A$\\
  $3=r$ in $B$
\end{tabular}
$\longrightarrow$
\tikznode{Z1}{$[(r,A),(i,C),(r,C)]=Z$}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{90/1/R,310/2/,350/3/\cross}\\
  Move
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{90/1/R,310/2/\cross ,350/3/R}\\
  Status
\end{tabular}

\paragraph{Time 3}\mbox{}\\
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5em}@{}}
  $1=r$ in $B$\\
  $2=r$ in $A$\\
  $3=r$ in $B$
\end{tabular}
$\longrightarrow$
\tikznode{Q1}{$[(r,C),(r,B),(r,A)]=Q$}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{90/3/R,210/2/\cross,330/1/R}\\
  Move
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{90/3/R,210/2/R,330/1/R}\\
  Status
\end{tabular}

At time 3, the epidemic stops since all personnel are recovered.

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,>=stealth',shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2pt]
  \draw[->] (X1) edge[bend left] node[right]{$P_{XY}=p/8$} (Y1);
  \draw[->] (Y1) edge[bend left] node[right]{$P_{XY}=p/8$} (Z1);
  \draw[->] (Z1) edge[bend left] node[right]{$P_{XY}=p/8$} (Q1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\newpage

\section{Case 3}

\paragraph{Time 0}\mbox{}\\
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5em}@{}}
  $1=i$ in $A$\\
  $2=s$ in $B$\\
  $3=s$ in $C$
\end{tabular}
$\longrightarrow$
\tikznode{X3}{$[(i,A),(s,B),(s,C)]=X$}
\board[0.9]{90/1/\cross,210/2/,330/3/}

\paragraph{Time 1}\mbox{}\\
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5em}@{}}
  $1=r$ in $C$\\
  $2=i$ in $C$\\
  $3=s$ in $A$
\end{tabular}
$\longrightarrow$
\tikznode{Y3}{$[(r,C),(i,C),(s,A)]=Y$}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{90/3/,310/1/\cross,350/2/}\\
  Move
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{90/3/,310/3/R,350/2/\cross}\\
  Status
\end{tabular}

\paragraph{Time 2}\mbox{}\\
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5em}@{}}
  $1=r$ in $B$\\
  $2=r$ in $B$\\
  $3=i$ in $B$
\end{tabular}
$\longrightarrow$
\tikznode{Z3}{$[(r,B),(r,B),(i,B)]=Z$}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{210/2/\cross,245/3/,175/1/R}\\
  Move
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{210/2/R,245/3/\cross,175/1/R}\\
  Status
\end{tabular}

\paragraph{Time 3}\mbox{}\\
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5em}@{}}
  $1=r$ in $A$\\
  $2=r$ in $C$\\
  $3=r$ in $C$
\end{tabular}
$\longrightarrow$
\tikznode{Q3}{$[(r,A),(r,C),(r,C)]=Q$}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{90/1/R,310/3/\cross,350/2/R}\\
  Move
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{90/1/R,310/3/R,350/2/R}\\
  Status
\end{tabular}

At time 3, the epidemic stops since all personnel are recovered.  

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,>=stealth',shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2pt]
  \draw[->] (X1) edge[bend left] node[right]{$P_{XY}=p/8$} (Y1);
  \draw[->] (Y1) edge[bend left] node[right]{$P_{XY}=p/8$} (Z1);
  \draw[->] (Z1) edge[bend left] node[right]{$P_{XY}=p/8$} (Q1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\newpage

\section{Case 2}
  
\paragraph{Time 0}\mbox{}\\
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5em}@{}}
  $1=i$ in $A$\\
  $2=s$ in $B$\\
  $3=s$ in $C$
\end{tabular}
$\longrightarrow$
\tikznode{X2}{$[(i,A),(s,B),(s,C)]=X$}
\board[0.9]{90/1/\cross,210/2/,330/3/}

\paragraph{Time 1}\mbox{}\\
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5em}@{}}
  $1=r$ in $B$\\
  $2=s$ in $A$\\
  $3=i$ in $B$
\end{tabular}
$\longrightarrow$
\tikznode{Y2}{$[(r,B),(s,A),(i,B)]=Y$}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{90/3/,210/1/\cross,330/2/}\\
  Move
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{90/3/,210/1/R,330/2/}\\
  Status
\end{tabular}

At time 1, the epidemic stops since all personnel are recovered.

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,>=stealth',shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2pt]
  \draw[->] (X3) edge[bend left] node[right]{$P_{XY}=1/8$} (Y3);
\end{tikzpicture}


\section{Case 4}
  
\paragraph{Time 0}\mbox{}\\
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5em}@{}}
  $1=i$ in $A$\\
  $2=s$ in $B$\\
  $3=s$ in $C$
\end{tabular}
$\longrightarrow$
\tikznode{X4}{$[(i,A),(s,B),(s,C)]=X$}
\board[0.9]{90/1/\cross,210/2/,330/3/}

\paragraph{Time 1}\mbox{}\\
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5em}@{}}
  $1=r$ in $B$\\
  $2=s$ in $A$\\
  $3=s$ in $A$
\end{tabular}
$\longrightarrow$
\tikznode{Y4}{$[(r,B),(s,A),(s,A)]=Y$}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{70/3/,210/1/\cross,110/2/}\\
  Move
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{70/3/,210/1/R,110/2/}\\
  Status
\end{tabular}

At time 1, the epidemic stops since all personnel are recovered.

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,>=stealth',shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2pt]
  \draw[->] (X4) edge[bend left] node[right]{$P_{XY}=1/8$} (Y4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\newpage
\section{Case 5}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: isn't it possible to have them in order?

Comment: @Math Sure it is possible. It is a trade-off: If you want to have them in order, you will have lots of space on the pages of Case 2 and Case 4, because they fill half of the page only, but they are too large to fit on the same page as case 1 and case 3. It is easy to do: just rearrange the LaTeX code, including the `\newpage`/`\clearpage`. You can also think about a less space-consuming arrangement of each step. But this is up to you: Only you know what you want to write. You can scale down the drawings, but they are cramped already now; experiment with the scaling factor, currnetly `0.9`.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
    \usepackage{bm}
    \usepackage{nccmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,arrows}
    \newcommand\tikznode[3][]{%
      \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#2.base)]
        \node[minimum size=0pt,inner sep=0pt,#1](#2){#3};%
    }
    % \board[optional scale factor, default 1.0]{list of triples angle/number/mark}
    \newcommand\board[2][1.0]{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,0)},scale=#1]
        \draw (0,0) circle (1);
        % radial lines at angles 30°, 150° and 270°
        \foreach \a in {30, 150, 270}
          \draw (\a:0.8) -- (\a:1.2);
        % label A/B/C outside of circle at angles 90°, 210° and 330°
        \foreach \a/\l in {90/A,210/B,330/C}
          \node at (\a:1.4) {\scriptsize$\l$};
        % draw game positions
        % \a ... angle, \n ... number 1/2/3, \m ... mark  
        \foreach \a/\n/\m in {#2} {
          % node
          \node[circle,draw,minimum size=1em,inner sep = 0,fill=white] at (\a:1) {\m};
          % number inside of circle
          \node at (\a:0.6) {\scriptsize$\n$};
      }
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
    \newcommand\cross{$\times$}
    
    \begin{document}
    \paragraph{Time 0}\mbox{}\\
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5em}@{}}
  $1=i$ in $A$\\
  $2=s$ in $B$\\
  $3=s$ in $C$
\end{tabular}
$\longrightarrow$
{$[(i,A),(s,B),(s,C)]=\tikznode{X}X$}
\board[0.9]{90/1/\cross,210/2/,330/3/}

\paragraph{Time 1}\mbox{}\\
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5em}@{}}
  $1=r$ in $B$\\
  $2=s$ in $A$\\
  $3=i$ in $B$
\end{tabular}
$\longrightarrow$
{$[(r,B),(s,A),(i,B)]=\tikznode{Y}Y$}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{90/2/,190/1/\cross,230/3/}\\
  Move
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{90/2/,190/1/R,230/3/\cross}\\
  Status
\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,>=stealth',shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2pt]
  \draw[->] (X) edge[bend left] node[right]{$P_{XY}=p/8$} (Y);
\end{tikzpicture}

\paragraph{Time 2}\mbox{}\\
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5em}@{}}
  $1=r$ in $B$\\
  $2=i$ in $A$\\
  $3=r$ in $B$
\end{tabular}
$\longrightarrow$
\tikznode{Y}{$[(r,A),(i,C),(r,C)]=Z$}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{90/1/R,310/2/,350/3/\cross}\\
  Move
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{90/1/R,310/2/\cross ,350/3/R}\\
  Status
\end{tabular}

\paragraph{Time 3}\mbox{}\\
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{5em}@{}}
  $1=r$ in $B$\\
  $2=r$ in $A$\\
  $3=r$ in $B$
\end{tabular}
$\longrightarrow$
\tikznode{Y}{$[(r,C),(r,B),(r,A)]=Q$}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{90/3/R,210/2/\cross,330/1/R}\\
  Move
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \board[0.9]{90/3/R,210/2/R,330/1/R}\\
  Status
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Let me edit the question to show you what I get.

Comment: I wish to put the arrow like how it was in case 1: Time 0. Otherwise it looks clustered.